# How to set text color dynamically in Ionic2

Tags: css, cordova, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to change text color as below.

Item.color returns RGB code like "#002200".
But the app does not run properly, it displays white screen.

```
<div style="color:{{item.color}}">{{item.name}}</div>
```

The below code works fine.

```
<div style="color:#002200">{{item.name}}</div>
```

How could I solve this problem? Or am I doing wrong approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty easy, just use [style binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#style-binding):

```
<div [style.color]="item.color">{{item.name}}</div>
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/flaQhvnySHBa5Z67DtMw) for example usage and show case

Answer (score -2):

you dont need brackets inside tags

```
<div style="color:item.color">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think that you haven't readed the question / answer. It's a answer that solve the question

Comment: I have no idea about CSS, and because your answer is worded in a way that made me think that it would better be a comment, I said that. My apologies.